# FFmpeg giving a wierd "Permission denied" error (Digitalocean VPS Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: php, ubuntu, ffmpeg

I've set up a VPS server on Digitalocean. Installed Ubuntu 18.04, LAMP, etc.
Finally, I installed ffmpeg. It is working fine from terminal but when I try to execute it through php it gives a weird "Permission denied" error:

Here is some information:
root@vl:/# whereis ffmpeg
ffmpeg: /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
root@vl:/# whereis ffprobe
ffprobe: /usr/local/bin/ffprobe

root@vl:/# ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version N-102461-g8649f5dca6 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/ffmpeg_build/lib --extra-libs='-lpthread -lm' --ld=g++ --bindir=/usr/local/bin --enable-gpl --enable-gnutls --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree
libavutil      57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
libavcodec     59.  1.100 / 59.  1.100
libavformat    59.  0.101 / 59.  0.101
libavdevice    59.  0.100 / 59.  0.100
libavfilter     8.  0.101 /  8.  0.101
libswscale      6.  0.100 /  6.  0.100
libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
libpostproc    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100

My php file:

echo shell_exec("ffmpeg -i mj.gif -profile:v baseline -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=600:-2 output.mp4 2>&1")
?>

The ERROR!:
ffmpeg version N-102461-g8649f5dca6 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/ffmpeg_build/lib --extra-libs='-lpthread -lm' --ld=g++ --bindir=/usr/local/bin --enable-gpl --enable-gnutls --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree libavutil 57. 0.100 / 57. 0.100 libavcodec 59. 1.100 / 59. 1.100 libavformat 59. 0.101 / 59. 0.101 libavdevice 59. 0.100 / 59. 0.100 libavfilter 8. 0.101 / 8. 0.101 libswscale 6. 0.100 / 6. 0.100 libswresample 4. 0.100 / 4. 0.100 libpostproc 56. 0.100 / 56. 0.100 Input #0, gif, from 'mj.gif': Duration: 00:00:01.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 22863 kb/s Stream #0:0: Video: gif, bgra, 1400x1050, 10 fps, 10 tbr, 100 tbn output.mp4: Permission denied

From the past 24 hours I've tried installing ffmpeg in different ways (compiling & apt install), I've also tried changing the permission but still I'm stuck with this error.
Any help would be highly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: How did you change permissions? In console will be a rol and Apache/PHP other.

Comment: I tried to change permissions of /usr/local/bin (chmod 755 /usr/local/bin and chmod 777 /usr/local/bin) then I tried to move user "www-data" to group "video" by using this "usermod -a -G video www-data".. nothing worked so far!

Answer (score 1):

Instead

```
echo shell_exec("ffmpeg -i mj.gif -profile:v baseline -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=600:-2 output.mp4 2>&1")
```

try something like

```
echo shell_exec("ffmpeg -i mj.gif -profile:v baseline -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=600:-2 /var/www/your_app/output.mp4 2>&1")
```

If it fails try chmod 777 /var/www/your_app

Comment: By executing "chmod 777 /var/www/html" it started working now. Is it a good practice to give "/var/www/html" 777 permission?

Comment: No, it is not a good practice, because it is the max privilege level. Once you got it working try to reduce privilege level (for example 755) and work with the most restrictive. If my answer has helped you, please accept it.

Comment: I upvoted your answer but I got an error "you need to have 15 reputation". I changed the permission for /var/www/html back to 755. I used chown to tackle this error, I've used a command "sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html" --> is it safe to use this one?

Comment: If www-data is Apache user and directory's owner even 700 should work. You may use a customized path for videos, not root path. For example /var/www/html/videos

Answer (score 0):

php shell stuff runs from a different user as root and you used root to execute it in the terminal. You would need to give the www-data user permission to run the file. probably because the file ffmpeg is trying to access (mj.gif) doesn't have permissions set for everyone to read the file. Try running `chmod 755 mj.gif` in the directory the gif is in.